# Duration not applying to all rows

Tags: javascript

I  created a music list similar to spotify dynamically is javascript and I am trying to add duration in all rows but the problem is duration is applying to first row only. And console not showing any error. i tried but couldn't figure what's the problem.

```
// Creating Music List
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
// let create tr tags according to array length for list
for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    //let's pass the song details from the array
    let trTag = `<tr tr-index = ${i}>
    <td class="numberlist" width="5%">${songs[i].nmbr}</td>
    <td class="title" width="80%">
        <div>
            <img class="cover1" src=${songs[i].coverPath} >
        </div>
        <div class="songdetails">
            <h3>${songs[i].trackName}</h3>
            <h4>${songs[i].trackArtist}</h4>
            
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="30%">
        <h4>${songs[i].trackAlbum}</h4>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">${songs[i].date}</td>
    <td width="5%">
        <img class="svg1" src="/assets/asset 72.svg" alt="">
    </td>
    <td width="12%" class="audio_duration">0:00</td>
    </tr> `;


    tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", trTag); //inserting the tr inside tbody tag

    let trAudioDuration = tbody.querySelector(".audio_duration");
    let trAudioTag = new Audio(`audio/1.mp3`);

    trAudioTag.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
        let aDuration = trAudioTag.duration;
        let totalMin = parseInt(aDuration / 60);
        let totalSec = parseInt(aDuration % 60);
        if (totalSec < 10) {
            totalSec = `0${totalSec}`;
        };
        trAudioDuration.innerHTML = `${totalMin}:${totalSec}`; //passing total duration of song
    });
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, this is a classic one! The problem lies with this:

```
let trAudioDuration = tbody.querySelector(".audio_duration");
```

See, `querySelector`, especially when using a class selector, only returns the first matched element. We need to use `querySelectorAll` here instead, which returns all of the matched elements.

Since `querySelectorAll` returns an array of multiple elements, we also need to handle the innerHTML setting a bit differently, so we use `forEach` to go through all of the matched elements and set the innerHTML on each of them.

Here's a snipped demonstrating the issue and the solution:

```js
function problem() {
  let tag = document.querySelector(".duration");
  tag.innerHTML = "1:53";
}

function solution() {
  let tags = document.querySelectorAll(".duration2");
  
  tags.forEach((tag) => {
    tag.innerHTML = "8:41";
  });
}

function secure_solution() {
  let tags = document.querySelectorAll(".duration3");
  
  tags.forEach((tag) => {
    tag.textContent = "8:41";
  });
}

problem();
solution();
secure_solution();
```

```html
<p>Problematic table</p>
<table id = "tbl">
  <tr><td class = "duration">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration">0:00</td></tr>
</table>

<p>Working table</p>
<table id = "tbl2">
  <tr><td class = "duration2">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration2">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration2">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration2">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration2">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration2">0:00</td></tr>
</table>

<p>Secure table</p>
<table id = "tbl3">
  <tr><td class = "duration3">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration3">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration3">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration3">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration3">0:00</td></tr>
  <tr><td class = "duration3">0:00</td></tr>
</table>
```

**On an important side note** you shouldn't use innerHTML to write the duration into the elements. Your duration is just text and contains zero html, so it is a better idea to use something like `textContent` instead. This ensures that some malicious party has no chance of injecting their own bad HTML to your page by somehow replacing duration data with HTML like `<script>alert("hax")</script>`. Notice how I actually just wrote HTML there, but StackOverflow has this thought out and your browser won't actually pop an alert box for you and only shows that as a text. If you ever DO need to use `innerHTML`, remember to [sanitize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) it first.

Comment: Good catch regarding to finding the issue. But OP might not want to set text for all elements with class `audio_duration`. I added answer to have minor update in query selector which should fix the issue. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Swiffy in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72796871/9695286) problem is there due to `tbody.querySelector(".audio_duration");` as it will select first `.audio_duration` element from `tbody`.

You can update that query selector like below and it should work well.

```
let trAudioDuration = tbody.querySelector(`tr[tr-index='${i}'] .audio_duration`);
let trAudioTag = tbody.querySelector(`tr[tr-index='${i}'] audio`);
```

**Explanation :**

- Selector `tr[tr-index='${i}'] .audio_duration` will find `tr` element inside `tbody` with attribute `tr-index` and its value specified with `i` and any of its child (including child of child and so on) having class `audio_duration` and return that element with class `audio_duration`.
- Selector `tr[tr-index='${i}'] audio` will find `tr` element inside `tbody` with attribute `tr-index` and its value specified with `i` and any of its child (including child of child and so on) `audio` element and return that `audio` element.

**Note :** [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will return first matching value from given selector. If you want to get all matching element then use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

**References :**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: it worked but now only song 1 duration is showing in whole list is there anyway to set duration of the particular song like the above one.

Comment: As you have not included `audio` element in your question it was not clear how you are going to use `trAudioTag`. From your answer it is bit clear. You can use selector as I have updated in answer. **P.S.**  `audio` element should be inside any `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because your selector `.audio_duration` is searching the `tbody` where all the `.audio_duration` elements are.

One solution would be to get the `tr` that you inserted and perform your selector on that and then it will look for `.audio_duration` in the `tr` instead of the `tbody`.

```
let tr = tbody.lastElementChild;
let trAudioDuration = tr.querySelector(".audio_duration");
```

Answer (score 0):

adding {src: "audiofilename"} in song array and modifying code like below worked out.

** - modified code

````
const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
// let create tr tags according to array length for list
for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    //let's pass the song details from the array
    let trTag = `<tr tr-index = ${i}>
    <td class="numberlist" width="5%">${songs[i].nmbr}</td>
    <td class="title" width="80%">
        <div>
            <img class="cover1" src=${songs[i].coverPath} >
        </div>
        <div class="songdetails">
            <h3>${songs[i].trackName}</h3>
            <h4>${songs[i].trackArtist}</h4>
            
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="30%">
        <h4>${songs[i].trackAlbum}</h4>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">${songs[i].date}</td>
    <td width="5%">
        <img class="svg1" src="/assets/asset 72.svg" alt="">
    </td>
    <td width="12%" id="${songs[i].src}" class="audio_duration">0:00</td>**
    <audio class="${songs[i].src}" src="${songs[i].filePath}"> </audio>**
    </tr > `;


    tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", trTag); //inserting the tr inside tbody tag

    let trAudioDuration = tbody.querySelector(`#${songs[i].src}`);**
    let trAudioTag = tbody.querySelector(`.${songs[i].src}`);**

    trAudioTag.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
        let aDuration = trAudioTag.duration;
        let totalMin = parseInt(aDuration / 60);
        let totalSec = parseInt(aDuration % 60);
        if (totalSec < 10) {
            totalSec = `0${totalSec} `;
        };
        trAudioDuration.textContent = `${totalMin}:${totalSec} `; //passing total duration of song

    });
};```
````